# Compare matrix with elements in vector by row

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to compare values of a matrix to a corresponding vector. The comparison should be performed row-wise.

Example matrix:

```
ret

                    TLT          VTI
1995-01-20 -0.005649718 -0.004461441
1995-01-23 -0.002840909  0.002560820
1995-01-24  0.000000000  0.000000000
1995-01-25  0.005698006  0.003831418
1995-01-26  0.000000000  0.001908397
```

VEctor to compare with:

```
compare.vec
[1] -0.001  -0.002
```

What I want is to compare each return element in column 1 of ret to -0.001 and find which one is smaller than -0.001. Vice versa for the second column, comparing it to -0.002 and finding the elements in VTI volumn that are less than that.

I tried subset, but it seems its not for a vector but a number. Will I need to loop column for column?

Thanks,

Comment: do you just want to compare or also replace those values by -0.001 and -0.002??

Comment: nope, just need the boolean matrix back. True for elements less than -0.001 for first column and -0.002 for second column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
t(t(ret) < compare.vec)
```

EDIT based on comment from Arun.

Comment: Nice attempt at using recycling. But, I don't think this is quite right yet. Try for ex: `ret < c(5, -0.002)`. The first columm should be completely TRUE, but it isn't. The recycling happens the other way (column-wise when you want row-wise). You should do: `t(t(ret) < compare.vec)`

Comment: the first should should contain 2 FALSE as the first two elements in in that column is less than -0.001...

Comment: @Arun Ah yea, I had a fear that's what would happen...should've checked it. Updated with your idea.